# Vertically & Horizontally Align inner DIV center of the page

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

My website landing page has `Container` DIV with 100% Height & Width. I am able to align the `InnerContainer` div in center horizontally but i am not able to put it in center Vertically. I changed several properties mostly result remains same.

I have same example of http://jsfiddle.net/cwkzq/12/ and i am not sure where i am doing things wrong. I would appreciate help on this.

**CSS Code**

```
html, body,form { height: 100%;  }
body { margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: 1; background-color:Aqua; }
.Container { width: 100%;height: 100%; padding: 0; font-size: 12px; border:1px solid green;
 vertical-align: middle;     }
.InnerContainer
{  vertical-align: middle; width: 400px;height: 350px; border-left:1px solid;
    border-right:1px solid; border-color:#f5f5f5;margin: 0 auto;  padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;  background-color:Red;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<!--  Container    -->
<div class="Container">
<div class="InnerContainer">
    <!--  TopMenu Bar    -->
    <div class="colorBar">

    </div>
    <!--  TopMenu Bar   -->
    <!--  Middle Part    -->
    <div class="MiddleWrapper">
        <!--  Left Title    -->
            <div class="Title">

            </div>
        <!--   Left Title   -->
        <!--   Large Image   -->
            <div class="ImageLeftWrapper">

            </div>
        <!--   Large Image   -->
        <!--  Logo Wrapper    -->
            <div class="LogoWrapper">

            </div>
        <!--   Logo Wrapper   -->
        <!--   Page Text Area  -->
            <div class="PageText">

            </div>
        <!--   Page Text Area   -->
        <!--  Search Bar    -->
            <div class="SearchBar">

            </div>
        <!--   Search Bar    -->
        <!--   Banner Images -->
            <div class="BannerImageWrapper">

            </div>
        <!--  Banner Images   -->
    </div>
    <!--  Middle Part    -->
    <!--   Menu Wrapper    -->
    <div class="MenuWrapper">

    </div>
    <!--   Menu Wrapper    -->
    <!--   Footer Section  -->
    <div class="FooterWrapper">

    </div>
    <!--  Footer Section  -->
</div>
</div>
<!--  Container   -->
```

Mostly all the example on net have fixed width& Height Container DIV while in my case my container div has 100% width & height

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally

Comment: It has been done nicely but i am afraid it might create problems as the main container has 1px height. I have to add vertical line which runs along with the page text so vertical line will grow dynamically in height. I  had issue in past with this as Vertical line didn't grow as the parent div had fixed height. I am not good with css that is why i want to avoid this & have a solution pertaining to my layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the exact size of the block you want to align it's the easiest way to do this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3YR3/)

add this style to your .InnerContainer

```
.InnerContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -175px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks. this works for my solution.. I appreciate solution from other users  also but yours is the one i was looking for...

Answer (score 23):

#### **[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356401/1057730) moved to the original question**

I did it: ([demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2872671))

The main trick in this demo is that in the normal flow of elements going from top to bottom, so the `margin-top: auto` is set to zero. However, for an absolutely positioned element acts the same distribution of free space, and similarly can be centered vertically at the specified `top` and `bottom` (does not work in IE7).

### This trick will work with any sizes of `div`.

#### HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi now you can used many method of this solution as like this

**Css**

```
.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
}
.wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wraptocenter {
    display: block;
    background:green;
    height:500px;
}
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
.child{
background:pink;
    min-height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wraptocenter">
    <span></span>
    <div class="child"> Hello I am child and ver and horz....</div>
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/w9dxv/1/

more info http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

---

if you want  **Center horizontal and vertical align**

**Css**

```
.chv{
width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chv">
    Center horizontal and vertical align
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/HkEVZ/1/

---

if u want **Center horizontally and vertically a single line of text**

**Css**

```
.alldiv{
width:400px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alldiv">
Center horizontally and vertically a single line of text
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/SVEtH/1/

---

if u want **Center horizontal and vertical align** Used to table properties as like this ..

**Css**

```
.parent{
display:table;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px red;
    width:100%;
}
.child{
display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:solid 1px green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
Center horizontal and vertical align
</div>
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/J3Zc6/2/