# Centering a div in the page

Tags: html, css

How do I center a div at the middle of my page in html using CSS?

Something like www.google.com, when you go to the site, you will see the search bar and the logo are centered in the middle of the page.

Any way to go around this?

Comment: Can u just make a fiddle link b'coz couldn't get your question.

Comment: you could just look at the code of www.google.com and see how they do it

Comment: General way is using `margin:0px auto`

Comment: @iStimple. That does not work.

Comment: probably try using jquery check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen?rq=1

Comment: Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sbirthare/fy5xkf3q/. Add more content if you want.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925852/vertically-horizontally-align-inner-div-center-of-the-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**MARKUP**

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">your content</div></div>
```

**STYLE**

```
.outer {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/5tbwtrk7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

center the div using `margin : auto`.

Html:

```
<div id="center"></div>
```

And css:

```
#center {
    margin : auto;
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "center_me">Some content</div>
```

corresponding CSS to center the div would be,

```
.center_me {
 dislay: table;
 margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

or,

```
.center_me {
 display: table;
 width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

Html:

```
<div id="element">your element</div>
```

css

```
#element {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```