# How can I get my html code display in a middle of page like google search page?

Tags: php, javascript, python, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

How can my result is displayed in the middle of page with the help of Html or javascript code. As you all have seen google in search page. I get my result in top center but I want in the middle like google page.
My Html code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Search</title>
<body>

    <center>Search: <input type="Text" Name="">
    <input type="Submit" value="Go"></center>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated. I'd avoid that.

Comment: The Google search page is not in the vertical middle. It just has some stuff at the top so it isn't at the very top. In my browser window, the button of the Google Search / I'm Feeling Lucky buttons don't quite reach half way down the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    <div style="top: 50%; left: 50%; position: absolute;">
        <div>Centered text</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution:

set width and height in css what you want.

HTML:

```
<html> 
    <head>         
        <title> Search</title>
    </head>           
        <body>
            <div id="centered">                               
                Search: <input type="Text" Name="">     
                <input type="Submit" value="Go">
            </div>                           
        </body>           
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#centered{
width:200px;
height:50px;
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;       
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6x3e/

Answer (score -3):

if you want to put you content in middle of the page you have to add some margin from top
use this code and adjust margin from top

```
<div style="margin-top:200px;" align="center">Search: <input type="Text" Name="">
<input type="Submit" value="Go"></div>
```

Comment: "down an arbitrary number of pixels" and "the middle" are usually not the same place.