# Vertical Aligned Div

Tags: css, html, center

Does anyone in here knows how to make a div go to the center of the page (vertically) no matter the screen resolution or window size of the user? As an example, the login page of Instagram. If you make your window smaller, the div will keep floating at the center until it gets to the top. I made that, but the problem was that when the user kept making the window smaller, the div was actually going out of the user window (to the top).

Here is the Instagram login page for the example:
https://instagram.com/accounts/login/

And here is my page for the other example:
http://www.farespr.com

Would appreciate an answer =)

EDIT: This is my main div code:

```
#wrapper2{
    width: 960px;
    height: 530px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -280px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: fixed;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px #f0f0f0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fafafa), to(#efefef));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa,  #efefef);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fafafa', endColorstr='#efefef');
}
```

Comment: could you show some code please?

Comment: @EricLemos this is the CSS code for the main div:
#wrapper2{
 width: 960px;
 height: 530px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -280px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: fixed;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px #f0f0f0;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fafafa), to(#efefef));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa,  #efefef);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fafafa', endColorstr='#efefef');
}

Comment: take a look at my answer, and use it as reference for your project

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work for any size div.

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BxLhz/**

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #cc333;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ha4PU/**

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc333;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-height : 200px) {
    #wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

where `max-height` = height of `.wrapper`

Comment: But again, I have the same problem I have right now. If I resize the window and make it really small, the top of the div gets lost in the upper part of the window and I can't get to it by scrolling. I do can scroll down, but not up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QNwa3/ If you try to resize the window it will get to a point were the text "test" will disappear and you wont be able to scroll to see it.

Comment: Still, I keep resizing my window (from bottom to top) and the top part of the div gets hidden and I can't scroll up to see the text.

Comment: There we go! I appreciate your time, effort and help. Thank you very much =)