# Vertically aligning a div inside a div?

Tags: css, html

What's a good way to vertically align a div inside another div, when the inner div has a static height? As to the height will be different sometimes. http://jsfiddle.net/daCt3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer">
 <div id="footerLeft">
 <div id="copyright">
 <!-- <copy> -->Copyright MyCorp &copy; 2013<!-- </copy> -->
     <br>Some more random stuff
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer-right">

 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*-- FOOTER --*/

#footer {
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:0px;
    background-color:#2C2E31;
    border-top:#242426 solid 2px;
    position:fixed;
    height:100px;

}

#footerLeft {
    margin-top:50px;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at other answers? Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879849/vertical-aligned-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Floating boxes for sticky behavior, % units in margins for columned views is what most people use in their sites. Inspect [google.org](http://www.google.org/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is described in an article here: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

I've updated your CSS to look something like this:

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* styling */
  bottom:0px;             
  width:100%;
  background-color:#2C2E31;
  border-top: #242426 solid 2px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
#footer[id] {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
}

#footerLeft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
} /* for quirk explorer only*/

#footerLeft[id] {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}

#copyright {
  position: relative; 
  top: -50%;

  /* styling */
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
} /* for quirk explorer only */
```

You can view an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/UbzcC/1/