# Vertically centering a div

Tags: html, css

thiv.net/mobile needs to work on mobile, and it does, however when I turn my ipod to vertical, it changes drastically, my problem is i need the whole lot, textbox, button and image to be centered vertically, or change on rotate. I think centering the div vertically is the best option, so what css would i use?

Currently i have tried:

```
.center
{
position:absolute
top:40%;
bottom:40%;
height:20%;
}
```

But that doesn't work, so maybe it should only be centered after rotating?
Any ideas?

Comment: [this article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) Hopely useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following CSS :

```
.center {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
 }
```

you can also follow the link of stack-overflow : [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height:

```
div.centered{
 height: 100px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Optional: `position: absolute | relative | fixed` depending on what you want to achieve

the margin-top should always be 0 - half of the height of your div to center.