# How to freely move elements within a section or div?

Tags: html, css, position

this is my first time trying out the position: absolute and I'm not sure if this is the right approach to get the results I wanted. The results I want are that my webpage to fill the full height and width of the browser resolution. I want a design similar to http://getbootstrap.com/, where:

Bootstrap

Sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile first front-end framework for faster and easier web development.

I looked at the source code and it seems they use:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

but it was hard for me to get it right and in my code the section only expands when I add something to it, but I move the section elements around (SmartPhone Photography and the message), it skips over it. Anyone knows how do the design like that of bootstrap website would be great. The header I believe is fine, the content space in the middle to freely move elements and footer on the bottom. Thanks!

My full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/JWDGd/

Comment: what are you not being able to do? Make the navi stick?

Comment: to be able to make the full width and height of the page depending on the size you are viewing. The navi does stick, but the section is still small, I want it vast to cover the whole page with the footer at the bottom. I want it just like bootstrap in other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to do in this case:

1) apply **sticky footer** -- [great solution for this is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689290/1873152)

2) **center your** `section` **vertically** -- [here is an answer to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Here is your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWDGd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put this into your CSS:

```
 position:absolute;
 top:90px;   /* you might change the value */
 left:100px; /* you may change the value, its like your x and y value */
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to add drag-ability to the div. You can do this with some javascript libraries like : http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: i would love to use these tools, but i dont know jquery yet, just html5, css3, and little javascript.

Comment: may be drag and drop will help? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp