# How to vertically center an image inside an .image_container that responds to page resizing

Tags: css

I am currently using the image container (below)

```
}
.image_container {
width: 570px;
height: 120px;
margin: 275px auto 0;
}
```

This code horizontally centers the div just fine, but I cannot figure out how to set automatic vertical alignment.  Any advice?

Comment: Refer to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally?rq=1.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  The item in the iframe jumps to the top of the page and stays horizontally centered.  The top margin is able to keep it on the page in the right spot with my current screen resolution of 1600x900, but on larger resolutions the top margin needs to automatically shift to center and with my current code that won't happen.

Comment: Ahh I see I see, you are also using an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have static heights to work with, you can use a couple of strategies for vertical centering.

The most simple is to combine `line-height` and `vertical-align: middle`:

```
.image_container {
    width: 570px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 275px auto 0;
    line-height: 120px;
}
.image_container img {
     vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class="image_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />    
</div>
```

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/ka8Hw/1/ (note: I removed your top margin for the demo)

The `line-height` rule is a sort-of hacky way for inline elements to treat the entire box's height as a single line. The image will treat the middle of the box as the line that it needs to align with. But, it will align so the bottom of the image rides the midpoint. So, we use `vertical-align:middle` to tell the image to align its midpoint with the line's midpoint.

**Documentation**

- `line-height` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height
- `vertical-align` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `text-align:center` for container and `line-height:120px` as the height of container, then set `vertical-align:middle` to `img` in the container.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/7L5UB/)

[image: center aligned image vertically and horizontally]

**HTML**

```
<div class="image_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image_container {
    width: 570px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;

    background:green;

    line-height:120px;
    text-align:center;
}

.image_container img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
.image_container {
    width:400px;
    height: 500px;
    background:#000;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ka8Hw/3/

Comment: This will scale the image so it is 150x150. Did you try this, say for example, with an image that is 50x50?

Comment: if u want to give width,height mention it otherwise leave it.