# Centering a div that is displayed as a table and absolutely positioned

Tags: html, css

As the title implies, I need to know how to center a div that has the following CSS rules applied to it:

```
display: table;
position: absolute;
```

The div should be right in the middle of the viewport, and, as per usual with `display: table;`, it should be the size of it's contents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: Nah, it's different with `display:table`, because it makes the div not vertically centered, but rather, top-aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

If the table has a fixed height and width of 400px then you can use this css:

```
.center {
    display:table;
    position:absolute;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background:red;
    left:50%;               
    margin-left:-200px;     <---- half of width
    top:50%;                
    margin-top:-200px;      <---- half of height
}
```

[**DEMO WITH CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/CqvYE/)

If the table has a dynamic height and/or dynamic width then you can use this jquery:

```
$('.center').css({
    'left': $(window).width() / 2 - $('.center').width() / 2,
    'top': $(window).height() / 2 - $('.center').height() / 2
});
```

[**DEMO WITH JS**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mtc9/)

Comment: Is there no other option than to use JS, if the div is dynamic in it's contents?