# Vertically center an element on the page with CSS?

Tags: css

I need to vertically centre an element of unknown height on a page.

I can vertically center it relative to a containing div with this:

```
.one {
  background: grey;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; 
 transform: translateY(-50%); 
  margin: auto;
}
.cont {
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lfrJx

However I cant get it to center vertically on the page:

```
.one {
  background: grey;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; 
 transform: translateY(-50%); 
  margin: auto;
}
.cont {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqLcB

Comment: [**CSS-Tricks.com - Complete Centering Guide**](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: check to this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ycjsp

Comment: `html,body { height: 100%; }` should do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally

Answer (score 1):

put this css :)

```css
.one {
  background: grey;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.cont {
display: table-cell;
  background: blue;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mFGeH

```
.cont {
  position:absolute;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```