# Javascript to put centered text at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I am trying to use javascript to insert some center justified text at the bottom of the screen.

So far I have

```
    var toInsert = document.createElement("div");
    toInsert.innerHTML = "text to insert";
    toInsert.style.position = "absolute";     
    toInsert.style.bottom = "0px";
```

this puts it at the bottom of the screen how I would like, but then when I try to use this

```
    toInsert.style.textAlign="center";
```

the center alignment seems to be overridden by the "absolute" property above, and the text is left justified.

How can I both put text at the bottom of the screen, and have it centered?
thanks.

ps. javascript not jquery, for use in a UIWebView on an iOS device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your div is 100% width.

```
toInsert.style.width = "100%";
```

```js
var toInsert = document.createElement("div");
toInsert.innerHTML = "text to insert";
toInsert.style.position = "absolute";
toInsert.style.bottom = "0px";
toInsert.style.textAlign = "center";
toInsert.style.width = "100%";
document.body.appendChild(toInsert);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it would be easier to get the element positioned correctly in CSS with a class identifier, then use javascript to add the class.

Since you're using absolute positioning, the CSS you're looking for might be:

```
left:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search on StackOverFlow and this was the first one that came up, I think your answer is already out there.

[Best way to center a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

here is my [Dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/c2f794f43bb75082236d) example