# Display text and images in the center of div

Tags: html, css, centering

I have an `<h2>` with two `<img>`'s (one on each side), and I want these to be displayed in the middle of a `<div>` like in the picture below...I've tried something but I managed only to center them horizontally and one on top of the other.

Reference image:
[image]

HTML :

```
<div id="kolom5Nav">
    <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Back" src="images/back.png" /></a>
    <h2>Evenementen</h2>
    <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Forward" src="images/forward_blue.png" /></a>
</div><!-- end kolom5Nav -->
```

CSS:

```
#kolom5Nav {
    display: table;
    height: 141px;
    width: 1440px;
    background: #fdd400;
    text-align: center;
}
#kolom5Nav #kolom4Back{

    vertical-align: middle;
}
#kolom5Nav #kolom4Forward{

    vertical-align: middle;
}
#kolom5Nav h2{
    color: #044584;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a JSFiddle for you. Basically adding `display: inline-block` to your `img` and `h2` elements and then adding a `line-height` on your `div` will give you the output you want.

HTML:

```
<div id="kolom5Nav">
    <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Back" src="images/back.png" /></a>
    <h2>Evenementen</h2>
    <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Forward" src="images/forward_blue.png" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#kolom5Nav {
    display: table;
    height: 141px;
    width: 1440px;
    line-height: 141px;
    background: #fdd400;
    text-align: center;
}
#kolom5Nav #kolom4Back{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#kolom5Nav #kolom4Forward{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#kolom5Nav h2{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #044584;
}
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b47q3f7/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for me! One more thing I want to know is if that this is a correct implementation or it is "forced" to show the result

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. This isn't a hack to show the result if that's what you're asking. Basically you're telling the browser to consider these elements like words on a page. So the alignment of them comes from `text-align: center;` and `line-height`.

Comment: @misterManSam thank you for editing that. I was trying to get it working but for some reason it didn't want to show me the code.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR - Just need to add an empty line after `HTML:`. Check the edit :)

Comment: @misterManSam Ah! I knew that until I needed it!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```css
#kolom5Nav {
    display: table;
    height: 141px;
    width: 1440px;
    background: #fdd400;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:141px;
}
#kolom5Nav h2{
    color: #044584;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="kolom5Nav">
    <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Back" src="images/back.png" /></a>
    <h2>Evenementen</h2>
    <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Forward" src="images/forward_blue.png" /></a>
</div><!-- end kolom5Nav -->
```

Comment: Ok, but it's not vertically aligned

Comment: @Valeriu92 per my answer below, if you add a line-height to the main div that is the same as your height you will center the content vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning the items in a vertically centered absolute positioned container and using inline block to center them horisontally within that vertically centered container: **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/gjsawbbq/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="kolom5Nav">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Back" src="images/back.png" /></a>
        <h2>Evenementen</h2>
        <a href="#"><img id="kolom4Forward" src="images/forward_blue.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#kolom5Nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 141px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fdd400;
    color: #044584;
    text-align: center;
}
#kolom5Nav .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
#kolom4Back, #kolom4Forward, h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

*[reference](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

To center things horizontally and vertically, you need to use table-cell, not table (and vertically align to middle).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9mb40vsx/

CSS:

```
#kolom5Nav {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 141px;
    width: 1440px;
    background: #fdd400;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#kolom5Nav a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
#kolom5Nav a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
#kolom5Nav h2 {
    color: #044584;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
}
```