# Button center positioning

Tags: css

I have a problem with center positioning a button in a row in a table.I used width and margin but it don't work.Can you help me? Here's the code for that button(in css):

```
 .subm {
position:relative;
width:130px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-image:url('background.bmp');
border:none;
color:white;
opacity:1;
height:25px;
outline:0 none;
box-shadow:1px 1px 2px black

}
.subm:hover {
background-image:none;
background-color:darkgray;
box-shadow:10px 10px 10px black
}

.subm:active {
color:black ;
font-weight:bold;
width:128px;
height:24px;
background-image:none;
background-color:dimgray;
}
```

Comment: add fiddle whats your button class

Comment: See : Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m2c2ahd0/1/, fun one : http://jsfiddle.net/m2c2ahd0/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply try this

```
button{
    height:20px; 
    width:100px; 
    position:relative;
    top:50%; 
    left:50%;
}
```

for just horizontal alignment use either

```
button{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc78Y/1017/)

Comment: `margin: -10px -50px;` ? to reflect half the height of the element ?

Comment: Yea I was asking myself why too

Comment: IMHO `-20px` should be `-10px` anayway I would have used `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to avoid having twice as much values to modify ^^

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I would use following code:

```
.subm {
  position:absolute;
  width:130px;
  height:25px;
  top: calc(50% - 13px); // 50% - 0.5 * height.
  left: calc(50% - 65px); // 50% - 0.5 * width.
}
```

And for the parent:

```
position: relative;
```

You can see [a working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lsqz7nj/)

Answer (score 0):

If you used width and margin: auto's and it's still not centering you may just need to add `display: block` to your `.sumb` class like so:

```
.subm {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:130px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url('background.bmp');
    border:none;
    color:white;
    opacity:1;
    height:25px;
    outline:0 none;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px black
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/re079odr/