# How can I put a picture in the middle of a page?

Tags: html, css

```
<img id="lighthouse_Logo" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/icons/lighthouse_Logo.png" />
```

**Css**

```
img#lighthouse_Logo{
height: auto; 
width: auto;
max-width:500px;}
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Define "middle". Vertically, horizontally or both.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally

Answer (score 2):

As you said middle of page and not center, I presume you mean horizontally:

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to your css.

If you mean vertically, this should work:

```
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Lighthouse_Logo {
    width: auto;
    height: auto:
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code places the logo in the center of the screen(horizontally and vertically):

```
#Lighthouse_Logo {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px:
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -200px 0 0 -300px;
}
```