# Preloader JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a preloader, I currently have this code, but it's not showing the preloader before the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".preloader-wrapper").show();
        $("body").hide();
     });

$(window).load(function(){
  $(".preloader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $("body").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

EDIT: Got it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}, 2000);

#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: what does your HTML look like? could you setup a JSFiddle or a stack snippet https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: because you are hiding the body...

Answer (score 2):

You can have it loaded first and on top. Then just remove it after the dom is loaded.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}, 2000);
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader"></div>
<h1>SUPER SIMPLE FULL PAGE PRELOADER</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! It just won't center now... [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally) (first answer)

Comment: It also won't hide the body until page load, which I want it to do

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `.preloader-wrapper` to be visible as default - use css for this.

Example:

```
.preloader-wrapper { 
  display: block;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't place something outside the `<body>` tag, so this means you shouldn't hide body using JS.

Remove:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".preloader-wrapper").show();
    $("body").hide();
 });
```

Change the second piece of your code to:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
  $(".preloader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: It does [this](http://i.imgur.com/t7lukgn.gifv) now. How can I get it to be centered on the entire page? I also want to make it **not** move the page, like the gif

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues is that you are hiding the entire body, which probably includes the `.preloader-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple Preloader with css and javascript. no need to add any library.
Sample Blog : https://www.kingsubash.com/simple-page-preloader-with-css-and-javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
//hide the preloader
document.querySelector(".preloader").style.display = "none";
```

}

```
.preloader{position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100vh;background: #fff;z-index: 9999;text-align: center;}.preloader-icon{position: relative;top: 45%;width: 100px;border-radius: 50%;}


<div class="preloader"> <img class="preloader-icon" src="/PATH-TO-IMAGE" alt="My Site Preloader"> </div>
```