# How to align div in center of a page?

Tags: css

I want a div which is centered vertically and horizontally i.e. in the centre of a page. I tried position: absolute and making the div's top right bottom left 0! But the problem is when i zoom in the page it overlaps with other header and other divs! PLEASE HELP ME! How can i position the div at centre of a page without overlapping other divs while zooming in the page?

Like i have tried:

```
.center{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Try setting margin `auto`

Comment: Oops! I forgot to mention margin: auto in my code. I tried that already but still doesn't work

Comment: give this a try ... https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/8a7L8dtv/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 7):

Try,

```css
html{
  height:100%;
}
body
{ height:100%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;

}
.center
{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

.center {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>Test Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To horizontally center a block element (like div), use margin: auto

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p><b>Note: </b>Using margin:auto will not work in IE8, unless a !DOCTYPE is declared.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Flex is the best solution, perfect position.

If you want this for a loader, just do a full size div with position fixed and use flex for the div content.

> Flex guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
body, html {
  height:100%
}

body {
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.mydiv {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">test</div>
```

Comment: I also think flex is the best solution for this. Just beware of some old browsers - it might need another solution for them.

You probably shouldn't use flex on the body to avoid influencing all the other elements on your page. Instead, use it on a wrapper-div surrounding your to-be-centered div. Like <div class="wrapper"> <div class="mydiv">test</div></div>
Give the wrapper 100% width and height and position fixed or absolute, as you prefer.

Comment: That still doesn't work! The div just overlaps with other elements while zooming the page! I want to fix it in its position

Answer (score 1):

Try This

HTML

```
<div class="center">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.center{
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%; 
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/8a7L8dtv/1/)

Hope this Helps..

Answer (score 1):

**2020.4.23**
coping from real project

```
    html, body {
        display:flex;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }


<div id="id01" style="width: 50%;height: 30%;background-color: red; margin: auto;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is Your HTML Body**
    `<div class="testbox">
        <!-- Your div body -->
    </div>`

**This is Your CSS**
    `.testbox {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }`