# why I can't center the image vertically and horizontally?

Tags: css

I use display: table to center the image, but It seems not work? why?
Any answer I will be appriciatelly. Thank you very much ！I can not find my mistake, could you help me?

```css
.wrapper4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 60px; 
  text-align: center;
  
}

.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="垂直居中demo" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper4">
    <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To vertically center *this* 100px image in *this* 300px div, you can add a 100px top margin to the image (because 300-100 = 200; 200/2 = 100), and set its horizontal margin to `auto`. No need for `display: table` etc.

```
.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
```

However, that is not very reusable. Will your images always be 100px? Will they always be square?

If not, you have to account for centering landscape & portrait images of different sizes.

The easiest way to do this, with modern web browsers (anything newer than IE9 from about 2013) is to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), as explained [in this answer by tombul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618259/3216970).

You could apply the flex rules directly to your `div` element, but again this is not very reusable. Another option is to create a CSS class for an element that centers its contents in a flex container. This CSS class is then applied in the HTML. The `wrapper` class now just handles the dimensions and appearance of the wrapper; the `wrapper img` class just handles the dimensions and appearance of the image. The alignment of the image is controlled by the `centerFlex` class. If you wanted multiple images with left, centered, or right-justification, you could create & apply similar rules to accomplish that.

FYI, you can include all [margins with the shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) `margin: top right bottom left`, or in pairs `margin: top&bottom left&right`

```css
.wrapper4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0px auto; 
}

.centerFlex {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="垂直居中demo" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper4 centerFlex">
    <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
.wrapper4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 60px; 
  align-items: center;
  
}

.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
      margin: 0 auto;
  
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="垂直居中demo" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper4">
    <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *table-cell* alignment rules need to be declared on the *containing element of the nested element you need to align*.

```
div class="wrapper4"> <!-- containing element (should be table-cell) --->
   <!-- element to align -->
   <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">      
</div>
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*An additional containing element has been inserted to wrap the nested `img` tag - we'll use this contiaining element to declare the `table-cell` rules to*

```css
.wrapper4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.wrapper4 .wrapper-cell {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper4">
  <div class="wrapper-cell">
    <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Alternatives

**Flex-Box**

```css
.wrapper4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex; /* Adjusted */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  /* Additional */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper4">
    <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">
</div>
```

**Absolute Positioning**

```css
.wrapper4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block; /* Adjusted */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  /* Additional */
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* Additional */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper4">
    <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">
</div>
```

**Relative Positioning**

```css
.wrapper4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block; /* Adjusted */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.wrapper4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* Additional */
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper4">
    <img src="http://listenwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/xiaogou.jpg" alt="小狗">
</div>
```

**CodePen Demonstrations**

1. [Horizontal Alignment (Arbitrary Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/vWGbdb)
2. [Vertical Alignment (Arbitrary Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/XzdGqO)