# NavBar margin: auto, does not work

Tags: html, css, navbar, margin

I have just a simple html:

```
<body>
    <header id="cabecalho">
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
<style>
          *{
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;    
          }
          html{
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
          }
          body{
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
          }
          header#cabecalho{
            width: 100%;
            height: 5%;
            background-color: rgb(60, 92, 86); 
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          nav#menu{
            display: block;
            height: 50%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
          }
          nav#menu ul{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            list-style: none;
          }
          nav#menu ul li{
              display:inline-block;
              color: white;  
          }


      </style>
```

I just want to vertical centralize the menu in the header, but it keeps on the top of it.
obs: using margin: x Pixels works, but i don't think this is the best way to deal with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to tackle this.

I would target the nav and header and give it a `position: relative;`. Then I would give the menu a `top: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%);`

This moves the menu 50% down the header and pulls it back up 50% of its own height. Resulting in a centred menu.

If you want to centre the text inside the menu, I would suggest doing the same for the ul.

You can look at this for reference [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azew9r8x/), but keep in mind that I have added a background to the menu and made the header larger for easy viewing.

Comment: how were you able to add answer after question was closed ?

Comment: Oh thanks! this really helped me!

Comment: @TemaniAfif Guess I started making an answer before it was closed

Comment: @Pedroleal No problem. Would appreciate if you marked my answer as correct :)

Comment: even if you started making an answer you won't be able to add it. If you didn't hit the "post answer" button even there is an anwser it won't work ... strage

Comment: Weird, I don't know.