# How to center a Modal in Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am new to the Semantic-UI-React framework, and recently ran across a problem that I can't seem to fix. I have a Log in & Sign up Modal on my home page. When the LogIn And Sign Up button is triggered, the Modal pops up. However, I cannot get it to appear in the center of the page. It is on the top of the page, and partially cut off. How do I go about doing this? 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 9):

The outer `<div>` containing the modal dialog has `display: block;` instead of `flex` which causes the misalignment. To be more specific, the definition `display: flex` of `.dimmed.dimmable > .ui.visible.dimmer` is for some reason overridden by `display: block !important` imposed by `.visible.transition`.

You might want to add the following to your CSS to fix this:

```
.dimmed.dimmable > .ui.modals.dimmer.visible {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

Or, if you are using css modules:

```
:global(.dimmed.dimmable > .ui.modals.dimmer.visible) {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

Comment: For me I need `justify-content: center;` to make it centered. I use SUIR 0.88.0 and I use css modules. Your `:global()` really did help me, thanks !

Answer (score 9):

I came across this issue when learning react just months ago and this is how I sorted this issue.In my .css file under App.js folder just add:

```
.modal {
    height: auto;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```

Hope it helps.Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are currently issues with the modal's in SUI check out this issue https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6185