# I can't seem to get the texts centered

Tags: html, css

So I'm using three different texts and the first class `.item-1` seems to be positioned properly but the second one goes slightly lower and the third one is way off at the bottom. I used the "margin-top" to get it centered but I feel like this isn't the best practice.

What are some ways to get them centered no matter what?

```css
.divider3 {
        background-image: url("images/people.png");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #b6b6b6;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .divider3 p {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding-top: 8%;
    }

    .item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        font-size: 6em;
        animation-duration: 20s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

    .item-1 {
     animation-name: anim-1;
        margin-top: -1%;
    }

    .item-2 {
     animation-name: anim-2;
        margin-top: -12%;
    }

    .item-3 {
     animation-name: anim-3;
        margin-top: -13%;
    }

    @keyframes anim-1 {
        0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-2 {
        0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-3 {
        0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="divider3">
        <p class="item-1">"Super fast service and clean environment!" <br /> - John Anderson, GA</p>
        <p class="item-2">"Plans have changed and I had to have a conference room within an hour and ThanksOffice was perfect for it!" <br /> - Ashley Green, CA</p>
        <p class="item-3">"Very professional and satisfies every need." <br /> - Sam Smith, NJ</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position:absolute` on the `p` elements and use a vertical centering solution which involves using `top:50%` and `transform:translateY(-50%)`. This means you don't have to add a unique `margin-top` to every `p` element.

I also added `position:relative` to the `.divider3` element so the `p` tags are positioned relative to that container.

**NOTE:** I noticed in another answer you said you don't want to use `position:absolute`. You will have to use `position:absolute` to take the element out of the natural document flow. Otherwise using `position:relative` the `p` tags will stack on top of each other and you will be constantly battling with CSS to adjust their vertical positioning. The more `p` tags you add it will get progressively harder to compensate for their vertical positioning, because they will get pushed further and further down the page.

```css
.divider3 {
        background-image: url("images/people.png");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #b6b6b6;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .divider3 p {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        margin:0;
    }

    .item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        font-size: 6em;     
        animation-duration: 20s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

    .item-1 {
     animation-name: anim-1;
    }

    .item-2 {
     animation-name: anim-2;
    }

    .item-3 {
     animation-name: anim-3;
    }

    @keyframes anim-1 {
        0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-2 {
        0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-3 {
        0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="divider3">
        <p class="item-1">"Super fast service and clean environment!" <br /> - John Anderson, GA</p>
        <p class="item-2">"Plans have changed and I had to have a conference room within an hour and ThanksOffice was perfect for it!" <br /> - Ashley Green, CA</p>
        <p class="item-3">"Very professional and satisfies every need." <br /> - Sam Smith, NJ</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: **That's not OP, who said using absolute position is not a good idea**

Comment: And even your code isn't working as expected by OP, paragraphs still changing their postitions

Comment: I added a note to explain why it is a bad idea to use `position:relative`.

Comment: I see Wizard beat me by about 12 minutes. Here's my [fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/8531zcde/) of the same vertical centering method.

Comment: @DudeCoder You did not use the vertical centering method, which Hastig Zusammenstellen referred to in their comment.

Answer (score 1):

These all are paragraphs, so they're appearing just below the preceding one.

You can change their `position` to be `absolute`.

I don't know why `margin-top` isn't working, so I removed them.

The code in action is this:

```css
.divider3 {
        background-image: url("images/people.png");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #b6b6b6;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .divider3 p {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding-top: 8%;
    }

    .item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        font-size: 6em;
        animation-duration: 20s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

    .item-1 {
     animation-name: anim-1;
    }

    .item-2 {
     animation-name: anim-2;
    }

    .item-3 {
     animation-name: anim-3;
    }

    @keyframes anim-1 {
        0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-2 {
        0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-3 {
        0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
        74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
        100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="divider3">
        <p class="item-1">"Super fast service and clean environment!" <br /> - John Anderson, GA</p>
        <p class="item-2">"Plans have changed and I had to have a conference room within an hour and ThanksOffice was perfect for it!" <br /> - Ashley Green, CA</p>
        <p class="item-3">"Very professional and satisfies every need." <br /> - Sam Smith, NJ</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Timggwp... Why not?

Comment: Not a good structure for a whole website. Because you have only a small piece of it and it satisfies the question but if you put that code into whole page, you will have to modify position everytime when you add new elements. It will be a mess.

Comment: @Timggwp... Do you have a better idea?

Comment: If you add `position: relative` to `.divider3` to define it as the reference for those absolute positions, you can put anything you want above and below it...

Comment: They don't seem to be vertically aligned and a horizontal scrollbar is being created. Good effort though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .divider3 {
        background-image: url("images/people.png");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #b6b6b6;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

.divider3 p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
}

.item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 6em;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

}

```
.item-1 {
    animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2 {
    animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3 {
    animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
    0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
    0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Delete margin top's for .item-1,.item-2 and .item-3 and use position absolute to p