# How to center a box to the center in CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created a box using `div` and have 4 more `div` inside it:

**HTML:**

```
<div className='main__container'>
        <div className='item'>Image</div>
        <div className='item'>Name</div>
        <div className='item'>Price</div>
        <div className='item'>Quantity</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main__container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

This is the output which I get:

[image: react_error]

I want to center the whole box to the center. I tried to use `margin: 0px auto` but it isn't working.

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Comment: `margin:auto` won't work on a 100% wide div

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Read answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)! Hope, you will find each of them useful. You can also read [this article of freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/)

Comment: @AbirSheikh, I followed the stackoverflow answer got it working

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
.main__container {
    // other 
    width: max-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    // other
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.